# How to take Python Input with mistakes

Tags: python-3.7

I'm making a script where you guess a movie based off of a quote from it. What I'm wondering is how I make it so that I can take "Terminator" and "The Terminator" and allow spelling mistakes to still be correct.

I tried to look it up but found pretty much nothing.

```
#Guess that movie, gives a quote and you have to guess it for points, add a high score system.
from random import randint

points = 0

quote1 = randint(0,3)
quote2 = randint(0,3)
quote3 = randint(0,3)
quote4 = randint(0,3)

movieQuoteEasy = ["You're going to need a bigger boat.", "I'll be back.", "Here's Johnny!", "Say hello to my little friend!"]
movieQuoteMedi = ["Luca Brazi Sleeps with the fishes.", "Whatever doesn't kill you simply makes you... stranger.", "You talking to me?", "I love the smell of Napalm in the morning."]
movieQuoteHard = ["Rosebud...", "How am I funny to you? what makes me so funny.", "They call it a Royal with Cheese.", "Go ahead, make my day."]
movieQuoteExtr = ["I tried... at least I did that.", "Gentlemen, you can't fight here this is the way room!", "I'm having an old friend for Dinner.", "The greatest trick the devil pulled was convincing the world he didn't exist."]


movieAnswerEasy = ["Jaws", "The Terminator", "The Shining", "Scarface"]
movieAnswerMedi = ["The Godfather", "The Dark Knight", "Taxi Driver", "Apocalypse Now"]
movieAnswerHard = ["Casablanca", "Goodfellas", "Pulp Fiction", "Dirty Hary"]
movieAnswerExtr = ["One Flew Over the Cuckos Nest", 'Dr. Strangelove', "Silence of the Lambs", "The Usual Suspects"]

print("Welcome to Guess That Movie!")

input()

#Easy Question
print("Easy: " + movieQuoteEasy[quote1])
guess1 = input()

#Takes the value for use input and checks it against the correct answer.
if guess1 == movieAnswerEasy[quote1]:
    print("Correct!")
    points += 5
    print("You have " + str(points) + " points!")

else:
    print("Wrong, the correct answer was " + movieAnswerEasy[quote1])


#Medium Question
print("Medium: " + movieQuoteMedi[quote2])
guess2 = input()

#Takes the value for use input and checks it against the correct answer.
if guess2 == movieAnswerMedi[quote2]:
    print("Correct!")
    points += 5
    print("You have " + str(points) + " points!")

else:
    print("Wrong, the correct answer was " + movieAnswerMedi[quote1])


#Hard Question
print("Hard: " + movieQuoteHard[quote3])
guess3 = input()


#Takes the value for use input and checks it against the correct answer.
if guess3 == movieAnswerHard[quote3]:
    print("Correct!")
    points += 5
    print("You have " + str(points) + " points!")

else:
    print("Wrong, the correct answer was " + movieAnswerHard[quote3])


#Extream Question
print("Insane: " + movieQuoteExtr[quote4])
guess4 = input()

    # Takes the value for use input and checks it against the correct answer.
if guess4 == movieAnswerExtr[quote4]:
    print("Correct!")
    points += 5
    print("You have " + str(points) + " points!")
else:
    print("Wrong, the correct answer was " + movieAnswerExtr[quote4])


print("\nGreat job, you have " + str(points) + " points.")
input()
exit()
```

I want to be able to take in 'The Terminator' and just 'terminator'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know how to solve your problem. The first thing you can do is add `.lower()` to the end of your input. This will put all of the letters in the user's input in lower case. Like this: `guess1 = input().lower`. Now it doesn't matter if the user types in upper or lower case. Also; you should do this:

```
guess1 = input(">>> ").lower() #Allows the user to input lower case letters.

if "terminator" in guess1: #This is probably what you are looking for.
                           #If the program detects the keyword 'terminator'
                           #in your guess, then the if statement will execute.

    #Whatever happens when the user is correct.
else:
    #Whatever happens when the user is incorrect.
```

I hope I helped you!